# Do not show video on webpage when screen is recorded/shared

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to prohibit screen sharing of videos on web pages?

For example, when you try recording or screen sharing (e.g. through Skype) a Netflix video, it only shows a black screen and there's also no audio.

My question is, how they implemented that? I could only think of JavaScript, but not how to do it. I've also searched the web many times, but couldn't find anything interesting. (Maybe I used the wrong search terms...)

Comment: I guess this is called copyright protection ^^

Comment: This might be of interest: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/46949

Answer (score 1):

<sup>I'll preface this by saying I'm not an expert in DRM or law. Please seek advice from a professional.</sup>

Sites like Netflix implement this by adding DRM to their content. Certain content must be played through a protected stream which can then allow the operating system to block things such as screen capture in certain cases. It's not foolproof however and there are plenty of ways to record the screen that wouldn't be detectable at all.

If I were you, I would subtly watermark my content and then protect my copyright via a strong legal defence. If you find anyone has copied your content, you can prove it was copied due to the watermark and have a strong case. It is better to deter users with a legal defence than actively block users as genuine users may end up with a degraded experience due to your efforts to protect your content.